# How to break from inner loop to the beginning of the outer loop

Tags: python

What's the best way to break from inner loop so I reach beginning of the outer loop

```
while condition:
    while second_condition:
        if some_condition_here:
            get_to_the_beginning_of_first_loop
```

Right now I got something like

```
while condition:
    while second_condition:
        if condition1:
            break
    if condition1:
        continue
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has the option of an `else:` clause for `while` loops. This is called if you do *not* call `break`, so these are equivalent:

```
while condition:
    while second_condition:
        if condition1:
            break
    if condition1:
        continue
    do_something_if_no_break()
```

and:

```
while condition:
    while second_condition:
        if condition1:
            break
    else:
        do_something_if_no_break()
```

Comment: Woah. Thats first am hearing about this.

Comment: @KaushikNP A more normal use is like `for x in mylist: if x==5: break else: print("No five found!")`

Comment: Nice. Good example.

Comment: `condition1` uses some variable defined inside of second block what to do in this case.?

Comment: @Poojan If you use the `else` trick in my answer then you only need `condition1` inside the second block, so I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on @ArthurTacca's answer, you use Python's `else` operator to make an elegant, arbitrary-depth break capability:

```
# Copied from ArthurTacca
while condition:
    while second_condition:
        if condition1:
            break
    else:
        do_something_if_no_break()
        # Minor addition
        continue  # This avoids the break below
    break  # Fires if the inner loop hit a "break"
```

Note that this else:continue/break pattern can be repeated to an arbitrary depth, and works for `for` loops too.